# Clustered Index Update on Nonclustered Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index, execution-plan

Using: SQL Server 2008 R2

I am currently stepping through a query execution plan, and have come across an instance of a clustered index update on a table.  The issue here is that the columns that are being updated are NOT part of the clustered index.

Table:

```
<table>
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) -- Clustered Index
    , name VARCHAR(20) -- Nonclustered Index
    , status CHAR(1)
    , quantity INT 
    , price FLOAT
```

Update statement:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.status = @status
    , a.quantity = @quantity
    , a.price = @price
FROM <table> a
WHERE a.name = @name
```

The execution plan shows an Eager Spool at 36% cost, a Clustered Index Update at 55% cost, and an Index Seek on the name index at 9%, among Compute Scalar and Top items at 0% cost.

Why is the plan showing a clustered index update?  What could I do to prevent this, and prevent the eager spool?

Comment: Is that definitely your exact query and table structure? Not sure why an eager spool would be added here,

Comment: @MartinSmith It's not, but the remainder of the table contains non-key columns that are proprietary and confidential. : /

Comment: Well can't you just anonymize them with `Col1, Col2` etc? The eager spool will probably be there for [Halloween Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx) but the query you posted and indexes you say you have don't appear to require this.

Comment: Sure, will update question.

Comment: Barking up the wrong tree with this question.  Will post a different question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have a clustered index on a table, **the clustered index IS the table!**

Mentally  you can substitute "table" for "clustered index" in this instance and it will make sense.

The data for every field in every row is **in** your clustered index.  The clustered index just sets the order of the physical pages in the database to be organized by your clustering key(s).

You can always fall back on the phone book analogy for these things, too:  in  your classic phone book, the data is clustered on `Last Name, First Name`.  Each entry still has `PhoneNum, Address` at the leaf level but you don't order by that.  The pages are in physical order by the the keys.

I can't advise on optimizing the query unless you show us the table and query you are running, but basically this cost will be paid one way or another.  If you don't update the clustered index it will be a table update and a table scan.

Comment: Could also add that the non-clustered index also has the clustering key in the non-clustered index, just for additional information. In this case the IX_Name index (or whatever it is called), also has the id column since it is the clustering key

Comment: @cairnz but it only exists at the leaf level

Comment: I know this answer was 5 years ago but thank you.  I've been looking for the answer to this forever!